# React-Redux - How to handle this state change in an immutable way

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutability

My API returns a list of nodes of the form:

```
 [
    {id: '2', parentId: '1', name: 'baz' },
    {id: '3', parentId: '1', name: 'bar' },
    {id: '4', parentId: '5', name: 'foo' },
    ...
 ]
```

and I display a tree structure using this information.

Currently my implementation saves the given list as state and my reducer first creates a clone of the existing state and then adds/updates/removes nodes from it immutably.

My react components however expect a list of children to be passed to them as a prop (not a part of the api response) so in my top most component I take the state and convert it into the required form and pass that down to lower components instead. The converted tree has the form:

```
{
    id: 0, name: 'root', 'children': [
        {id: '2', parentId: '1', name: 'baz', children: [{..., children: [...]}, {..., children: [...]}, ... },
    ...]
}
```

i.e a hash-map version of the tree with each child stored in a list on their parent, and the root of the tree being the outer most object, which is then passed down.

Now on every state change the stored state is converted to this form, but with a large amount of nodes this re-structuring causes delay on every state change, so I'm planning to store the state directly in this form (i.e `state = root`) and only re-structure the API response once.

I am not sure though how to do state changes for this in an immutable way. Lets say I want to add a new child to a specific node which is deep down the node hierarchy, doing this in a mutable way is easy: I simply push the child into the parent node's children list but how do I do this immutably?

or what is another way to go about this?

Comment: use Object.assign. or in array. Array.from(new Set(array.concat(newArray))

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [immutablejs](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) and [treeutils](https://github.com/lukasbuenger/immutable-treeutils)